# Delete rows and sections with commitEditingStyle

Tags: swift, tableview, edit, delete-row

I have a tableView where I show 0bjects which I create in another class. The objects are stored in an Array.

```
var whiskyArray = [WhiskyBuilder]()
```

Out of the whiskyArray I create a dictionary to move the data into the tableView. The dictionary is made with first letter as key and the names of the objects as value:

```
var alphabetizedWhiskies = [String: [WhiskyBuilder]]()
```

Now I would like to delete the cells with the `commitEditingStyle:` from the tableView, which I do with the following method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete { 

        alphabetizedWhiskies[Array(alphabetizedWhiskies.keys.sort())[indexPath.section]]!.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        if alphabetizedWhiskies[Array(alphabetizedWhiskies.keys.sort())[indexPath.section]]!.count == 0 {

    alphabetizedWhiskies.removeValueForKey(Array(alphabetizedWhiskies.keys.sort())[indexPath.section])

    tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index:indexPath.section), withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        }else {

            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

            alphabetizedWhiskies.removeValueForKey(Array(alphabetizedWhiskies.keys.sort())[indexPath.row])

        }
}
```

This method works actually perfect, the cells are deleted. But everytime I return to this view, the deleted cells are back in the table again.
I’m new in swift, but I think this happens because the cells are deleted in the dictionary but the objects in the whiskyArray are not. I tried to delete the objects in the whiskyArray:

```
whiskyArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
```

But with this, any object in whiskyArray is deleted, but not the one I would like to delete. So how do I acces the right object to delete in the whiskyArray by deleting the cell in tableView. I have found a lot about deleting tableViewCells, but I don’t find out, how to delete the meaning object in the Array. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that it is actually being removed from the data. When you delete it from the array it is just a local copy and when you leave the view and come back my guess is that you are reloading the data into the array essentially starting all over again. It has nothing to do with your UITableView code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... You have multiple issues here from what I can tell.

First thing, Whatever value you are using in

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return ???????????
}
```

is not being changed when you delete whatever you delete. The reason that the row disappears is because you manually deleted the row and then when you reload the view tableView.reloadData() is called.

I wouldn't use these lines.

`tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index:indexPath.section), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)`

The fact that this function is running means the tableView is already planning on deleting the corresponding indexPath... unless you really want to delete more than just that indexPath.

Next... every time a view controller is dismissed (which happens when returning to a previous view or using a Show Detail Segue and other conditions) you will lose the status of the viewController and viewDidLoad will start you back at square one unless you store the information in permanent storage like Core Data.

The next thing is that you are using sort functions. Because you are using them, you have to make sure that the information in whiskyArray is sorted in the same manner or the deleted object will seemingly be random.